# How to create Thread in JDBC?

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

---

**UPDATE**

To resolve this problem:

- make ResultSet final
- remember to Thread.sleep() rest of your code

*Thanks Leo for help*

---

I'm trying to add a Thread to my JDBC connection class and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. My IDE suggest that I should make my ResultSet rs "final" but that doesnt make any sense for me. When I run my code I get an error in line where i declare ResultSet:

```
   Exception in thread "Thread-1" 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code       
    - unreported exception java.sql.SQLException; must 
    be caught or declared to be thrown
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
    public class Main  {

    static final String url = "***** ";
    static final String login = "******";
    static final String pass = "*******";

   public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, InterruptedException {

    Main g = new Main();
    Connection polaczenie = null;
    Statement stat = null;

    try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
            polaczenie = DriverManager.getConnection(url,login,pass);

            System.out.println("Creating statement ...");
            stat =         polaczenie.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);


         // HERE I WANT TO START MY FIRST THREAD
            new Thread(){

            public void run(){
            String sql ="SELECT IMIE_AUTORA, NAZWISKO_AUTORA, AUTORZY_ID FROM AUTORZY";
           // HERE iS AN ERROR
            ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(sql);

                try {
                    while(rs.next()){

                        // rs.absolute(6);
                        String imieA = rs.getString("IMIE_AUTORA");
                        String nazwiskoA = rs.getString("NAZWISKO_AUTORA");
                        int idA = rs.getInt("AUTORZY_ID");

                        System.out.println("Imię autora: "+imieA);
                        System.out.println("Nazwisko autora: "+nazwiskoA);
                        System.out.println("id Autora: "+idA);

                    }
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
             }
            }.start();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then i get another error:                                   Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.UpdatableResultSet.cancelRowChanges(UpdatableResultSet.java:2890)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.UpdatableResultSet.next(UpdatableResultSet.java:289)

Comment: remove the flags ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE

Comment: Now error is gone but I dont get my output :(

Comment: keep rs.absolute(6); commented

Comment: It is commented already :)

Comment: what output do you get?

Comment: Edit and Update your question

Comment: maybe your main thread must wait for your query thread to complete first...

Comment: Yup that was the case! Thank You :)

Comment: JDBC resources are thread bound. You are not allowed to use a connection, statement or result set across different threads. (Nevertheless, that is not the reason for your error)